# Manage project meta-data with JIRA?

Tags: .net, documentation, project-management, bug-tracking, jira

Perhaps I'm missing this functionality out of the box, but I can't seem to find it. So I'm looking for a JIRA plugin that would allow for adding notes attached directly to the project summary page.

This would be for keeping track of odds and ends about a project that are important to document, but don't fit as bugs, code comments, spec docs or other official documentation types.  It's for "project metadata" if you will.  Examples of use would be things like:

- Documenting reasons for structural oddities for new developers
- Developer X customized jQuery widget Y (see Ticket Z) so if you upgrade the widget, make sure Ticket Z doesn't reopen.
- XYZ.dll is currently a beta version, it should be updated when ThirdParty finishes the final

FogBugz provides a project wiki. Are there any plugins for JIRA like that?

Open to all suggestions, including writing our own if it's relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We post our project level information on confluence and link the JIRA project with this page using the project level URL.

That way we can keep the project metadata (such as high level designs, dependencies to third party components, project objectives) in sync with reports that are retrieved from the JIRA instance.

In general, we keep everything which needs free form discussions on confluence, and everything which needs structural processing (such as issues, requirements ...) on JIRA.

I'm not aware of a plugin which provides that level of functionality in the context of JIRA.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into creating a plugin that adds specific pieces of metadata to a JIRA project but for the sorts of things you mention, I'd recommend Confluence.

~Matt